# Cast a textview on chromecast

Tags: text, textview, scroll, chromecast

Is it possible to cast a scrolling textview on chromecast with defaut receiver ? Or must i implement a custom receiver?

Thanks for response,

Cali

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom receiver.